# My sim800l works only when connected to laptop with serial monitor open

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I have this code where it sends DHT11 values through SMS when it receives the word SEND but all this setup works only when my arduino nano is connected to the laptop and serial monitor is open , otherwise if i connect to power bank or wall charger it doesnt send me the values. even when its connected to the laptop it doesnt send if i dont open the serial monitor.

this is the code

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "DHT.h"


#define DHTPIN 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11);

int index = 0;
float h;
float temp;


char incomingByte;
String incomingData;
bool atCommand = true;
String message = "";
String number = "";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();

  while (!mySerial.available()) {
    mySerial.println("AT");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("connecting....");
  }

  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");  //Set SMS Text Mode
  delay(1000);
  mySerial.println("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0");  //procedure, how to receive messages from the network
  delay(1000);
  //mySerial.println("AT+CMGL=\"REC UNREAD\""); // Read unread messages
  mySerial.println("AT+CBAND=DCS_MODE"); 
  Serial.println("Ready to receive Commands..");
}

void loop()
{


  if (mySerial.available()) {
    delay(100);
    // Serial buffer
    while (mySerial.available()) {
      incomingByte = mySerial.read();
      incomingData += incomingByte;
    }
    delay(10);
    if (atCommand == false) {
      receivedMessage(incomingData);

    }
    else {
      atCommand = false;
    }
    //delete messages to save memory
    if (incomingData.indexOf("OK") == -1) {
      mySerial.println("AT+CMGDA=\"DEL ALL\"");
      delay(1000);
      atCommand = true;
    }
    incomingData = "";
  }
  if (message.indexOf("SEND") > -1) { //
    SendTextMessage();
    Serial.println("send");
  }
}


void SendTextMessage()
{


  // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
  float temp = dht.readTemperature();
  // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
  float f = dht.readTemperature(true);

  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //To send SMS in Text Mode
  delay(1000);
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"" + number + "\"\r"); // change to the phone number you using
  delay(2000);
  mySerial.print("Humidity: ");
  mySerial.print(h);
  mySerial.print(" % ");
  mySerial.print("Temperature: ");
  mySerial.print(temp);
  mySerial.println(" *C ");
  delay(200);
  mySerial.println((char)26);//the stopping character
  delay(1000);

}
void receivedMessage(String inputString) {

  //Get The number of the sender
  index = inputString.indexOf('"') + 1;
  inputString = inputString.substring(index);
  index = inputString.indexOf('"');
  number = inputString.substring(0, index);
  Serial.println("Number: " + number);

  //Get The Message of the sender
  index = inputString.indexOf("\n") + 1;
  message = inputString.substring(index);
  message.trim();
  Serial.println("Message: " + message);
  message.toUpperCase(); // uppercase the message received
  Serial.println("receive");

  delay(50);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Try with LED debugging, put `digitalWrite(13, HIGH)` on the end of `setup()` and watch it. If LED turn on it complete setup(), if not move it above and see where program stop.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem.
The only way I get rid of it is to define all the SerialMonitor instructions like:

```
Serial.begin(x);
Serial.println(x);
```

To be conditionally compiled, only when I run the programm connected to the laptop. So, you can create a #define like:

```
#define DEBUG 1
#ifdef DEBUG
#define startupMonitor(x)     Serial.begin(x)
#define monitorPrint(x)       Serial.print(x)
#else
#define startupMonitor(x)     
#define monitorPrint(x)
#endif
```

When I deploy the program to the Arduino to make a Test of it disconnected I comment out the #define. This will remove all references to the Serial port of the Arduino serial monitor in the executable code and at least for me the SIM800L worked when disconnected.

I don´t know why this occurs, but there is only two devices using serial port communication, the SIM and the Arduino itself with the laptop, so I removed the Arduino, after all when disconnected you don´t need the Serial Monitor ;)

Conclusion: separate production code from development code using conditional compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset the Arduino by pressing the reset button on the board after the GSM module catch the network. It worked for me.